# Learned C#, told to learn ASP.NET but confused

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to apologize in advance, I think this may be a commonly asked question and I hate to repeat it, although I did search for a bit I couldn't come up with any results that answer my question, which is;

I've spend the last 8-9 months self teaching myself C# and I have come along pretty well, I can build my own small programs. I asked some people from various different places what my next step should be, they mostly said to learn ASP.NET, so thinking it was easy I didn't press for further information. A few days later I go to search for some tutorials/practice vids and information for ASP.NET to find out there's so many versions and different types that I had no idea where to begin. I've heard a lot about ASP.NET 3.5 I think it's called, but then lots of people are talking about something called ASP.NET MVC.

So finally to my question, for web related things, what version/type/name of ASP.NET do I need to learn? My guess is the ASP.NET 3.5, but I really want to be sure before I put months of learning into it.

Comment: The latest released version of ASP.NET is 4.0. See http://asp.net for information.

Comment: The 3,.5 and 4.0 are simply the version numbers of the .NET Framework. There is no ASP.NET "version" apart from the .NET Framework. So that part is easy. But other than that, I don't think this question isn't worth answering, because the amount of information about it on the web is huge, and "Where to begin?" is a valid and very good question!

Comment: The obvious counter-question is "what do you want (to become)".  Considering the general job market and the way things are going I would focus on MVC.

Comment: "Where to begin"-type questions are more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Then vote to move it there instead of closing it. Yeah, I know, you didn't close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start here: http://asp.net

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms)

And google search.